# Integration tests for DRF using pytest

Tags: django-rest-framework, pytest

I have a DRF api for the following:

1. paint a picture
2. package it

The important thing is that for each picture, packaging can happen only after painting
Also, there are two roles - **painter** and **seller**. Painter has permissions for painting, while seller has permissions for packaging.

Currently, I have the following setup:

conftest.py:

```
from rest_framework.test import APIClient


@pytest.fixture
def client():
    return APIClient()


@pytest.fixture
def user_1(user_password):
    return User.objects.create_superuser(
        username='painter',
        password=user_password,
    )


@pytest.fixture
def user_2(user_password):
    return User.objects.create_superuser(
        username='seller',
        password=user_password,
    )


@pytest.fixture
def painter_client(client, user_1):
    client.force_login(user_1)
    return client


@pytest.fixture
def seller_client(client, user_2):
    client.force_login(user_2)
    return client
```

tests.py:

```
def test__paint(painter_client):
    payload = {...}
    response = painter_client.post('paint', payload)
```

Ok, so now I need to test the packaging

**Question 1.** Is it considered a good practice to create a fixture for painting by calling the production code for "painting" like this? Or I should mock that instead?

conftest.py

```
pytest.fixture
def painting(painter_client):
   payload = {...}
   response = painter_client.post('paint', payload)
   # Fetch painting from db
   return painting
```

test.py

```
def test_packaging(painting, seller_client):
    payload = {...}
    response = painter_client.post('package', payload)
    # assert ...
```

**Question 2.** For some reason, in test_packaging, when I call painter_client.post('package', payload), the request.user is still user_1 (the painter). What is the reason for this, and how to fix it?